# How to set a static Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you look at this page, you notice that the background image does not move

http://livingsocial.com/deals/31570-86-off-boot-camp-classes?msdc_id=13

1) How is this done?

2) Why doesn't Twitter do something similar (ie, what are the UI disadvantages?)

Comment: Some computer systems don't scroll very smoothly when the background is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

My my.

Comment: Don't you mean `background-atatchment: fixed;`?

Answer (score 3):

It's done with pure CSS:

```
body
{
  background-image: url('foo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
body {
     background: #fff url(path/to/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

As to 'why doesn't Twitter do this?' That's not something we can answer, really, unless the Twitter devs are present on Stack Overflow. Historically using it has meant the page tends to scroll somewhat 'clunkily,' but that might just be the added rendering requirements placed on the browser, rather than implicit in the behaviour, or use, of `background-attachment`.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a large `div` there with the background, and `position: fixed`.

`position: fixed` means it won't move when the viewport scrolls.

2) I don't know... they probably would if they wanted the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

One line is all you need

```
background:transparent url(img.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 0;
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/dFJCt/